# Show that $K = \{ 0 \} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact (without using Heine Borel). Is my proof right?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I´ve been filling some analysis gaps studying with the "baby Rudin", so I still feel a little bit insecure.

Now, exercise 12 of chapter 2 states: Show that $ K \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $K = \{ 0 \} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is compact (without using Heine Borel).

So, my proof is the following, and I would like to know if it is correct or if it needs some more details.

Proof: Let $\{G_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $K$, i.e. $K \subset \bigcup_\alpha G_\alpha$. Since $0$ is a limit point of $K$ (every neighborhood of $0$ with any radius $r>0$ contains at least one point different to $0$ which is contained in $K$), every neighborhood of $0$ contains infinitely many points of $K$ (Theorem 2.20). Let $N$ be such a neighborhood with some radius $r>0$. Then $N \subset \bigcup_\alpha G_\alpha$, i.e. $N$ is a subset of $\{G_\alpha\}$. Let $G_{\alpha_1}, ..., G_{\alpha_n}$ be the finitely many open sets of $\{G_\alpha\}$ which contains the finitely many points of $K$ that are not in $N$, then it follows: $$K \subset N \cup G_{\alpha_1}\cup  ... \cup  G_{\alpha_n}$$
Hence, $K$ is compact.

Comment: The complement of $N$ can also have infinitely many points, so your proof is not correct.

Comment: I believe that "without using Hine Borel" (may be in hidden form) is not easy: K is closed and bounded and so compact.

Comment: @geetha290krm why though? $0$ is the unique limit point of this set. So, if the complement of $N$ has also infinitely many points, these are at least not contained in $K$, right? Thanks for the fast comments!

Comment: @lib definitely do not need Heine Borel - in any metric space a convergent sequence adjoined to its limit is compact.

Comment: No need for limit points. Just use the fact that $\frac 1 n \to 0$,  $G_{\alpha}$ contains **all but finitely many points** of $K$.

Comment: I just wanted to solve the problem as Rudin intended, withouth further concepts as limits or, as he specifies, without Heine-Borel.